# How to implement OR operator in Moongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am currently working on a website builder in Node where the user can add different types of custom components to build a website.

I am having an issue with my mongoose model where I am trying to define the website as an array of different components and each components can be one of 3 different types (i.e. the OR operator)

I am trying to use the native js || key but it is not working and I am not able to find a valid solution online

Please see my code below of combining multiple different schema into a top level website schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const headingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  componentId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  details: {
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    fontSize: { type: String, required: true },
    fontType: { type: String, required: true },
    color: { type: String, required: true },
  },
});

const textSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  componentId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  details: {
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    lineHeight: { type: String, required: true },
    fontType: { type: String, required: true },
    color: { type: String, required: true },
  },
});

const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  componentId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  details: {
    imageName: { type: String, required: true },
    imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    width: { type: String, required: true },
  },
});

const websiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  owner: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  components: {
    type: [headingSchema || textSchema || imageSchema],
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Website", websiteSchema);
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: There is a mixed type but it basically removes any type checks so no what you want probably

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [Mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) type like shown below:

```
const websiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  components: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

But this means, `components` can accept any values, and not necessarily `headingSchema | textSchema | imageSchema`